# python re.sub replace number in match string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Replacing numbers in a string after the match.

```
t = 'String_BA22_FR22_BC'
re.sub(r'FR(\d{1,})','',t)
```

My desired output would be `String_BA22_FR_BC`

Comment: Try using a lookbehind instead to match the digits `(?<=FR)\d+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'FR\d+','FR',t)
```

Alternatively, you may capture the part you need to keep with a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and replace with `\1` [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html):

```
re.sub(r'(FR)\d+', r'\1', t)
         ^--^- >>>----^
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E9hObh)

A capturing group approach is flexible as it allows patterns of unlimited length.

Comment: Thanks.  I've `re.sub(r'(FR|ZZ)\d+', r'\1', t)`.  This allowing me search multiple character groups.

Comment: @user3525290 Yes, you will even be able to use something like `re.sub(r'((?:FR|ZZ)[a-z]*)\d+', r'\1', t)` using this approach if need be.

Comment: I am guessing `[a-z]` is checking for upper or lower case?

Comment: @user3525290 `[A-Za-z]*` will match 0 or more ASCII letters. `[^\W\d_]*` will match any 0+ letters. `[a-z]*` only matches 0+ lowercase ASCII letters if `re.I` flag is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing what you match (in this case `FR22`) with an empty string.

Another option is to use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) an then match 1+ digits adn replace that match with an empty string:

```
(?<=FR)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIMftN/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1hxyOz)

For example:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=FR)\d+','',t)
```